# Building a DLL with both assembly and C++ functions

Tags: c++, assembly, dll, masm

I need to create a single DLL containing both C++ and MASM functions. 
I compile C++ files with g++ which outputs .o files.

Is it possible to use these with MASM linker? If not, how can I link these?

**Edit:** 
I tried converting `.o` file to `.obj` using `objconv` utility and then linking it with assembly object files but it didn't work.

Here are the commands I used:

```
g++ -mabi=ms -c copy.cpp 
objconv -fcoff64 copy.o copy.obj

C:\masm32\bin\ml /c /Zd /coff init.asm series.asm windows.asm

C:\masm32\bin\link /DLL /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /DEF:mydll.def /LIBPATH:c:\masm32\lib init.obj series.obj windows.obj copy.obj
```

And the output is:

```
copy.obj : fatal error LNK1136: invalid or corrupt file
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use g++ to link object files produced with g++.

Comment: Obviously you should use `g++ -O3`, otherwise you might as well just use MSVC's C++ compiler.  But as SergeyA says, you should try using `objconv` to convert the MASM outputs into a format that `g++` can link.

Comment: @PeterCordes this worked, but how do I use the `.def` file when linking with `g++`?

Comment: No clue, sorry.  I don't use Windows.  Maybe edit your question to ask that as an alternative.

Comment: You're compiling C++ code with g++, which will name-mangle differently from MSVC, potentially making `copy.obj` look like a corrupt file. Try `external "C"`.